# How to scrape .csv files from a url, when they are saved in a .zip file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I am trying to scrape some `.csv` files from a website. I currently have a list of links:

```
master_links = [
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20161201damlbmp_zone_csv.zip', 
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20160301damlbmp_zone_csv.zip', 
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20160201damlbmp_zone_csv.zip']
```

when I try to use:

```
pd.read_csv(master_links[0])]
```

it returns an error because each `.zip` file contains multiple `.csv` within them. I understand why this isn't working, but I haven't figured out how to unzip these files, and then put the .csv files into pd.read_csv without saving everything to my computer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a custom file reader for [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) like:

#### Code:

```
def fetch_multi_csv_zip_from_url(url, filenames=(), *args, **kwargs):
    assert kwargs.get('compression') is None
    req = urlopen(url)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(req.read()))

    if filenames:
        names = zip_file.namelist()
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename not in names:
                raise ValueError(
                    'filename {} not in {}'.format(filename, names))
    else:
        filenames = zip_file.namelist()

    return {name: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name), *args, **kwargs)
            for name in filenames}
```

Some Docs:
 ([ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)) ([BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)) ([urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen))

#### Test Code:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

master_links = [
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20161201damlbmp_zone_csv.zip',
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20160301damlbmp_zone_csv.zip',
    'http://mis.nyiso.com/public/csv/damlbmp/20160201damlbmp_zone_csv.zip']

dfs = fetch_multi_csv_zip_from_url(master_links[0])
print(dfs['20161201damlbmp_zone.csv'].head())
```

#### Results:

```
         Time Stamp    Name   PTID  LBMP ($/MWHr)  \
0  12/01/2016 00:00  CAPITL  61757          21.94   
1  12/01/2016 00:00  CENTRL  61754          16.85   
2  12/01/2016 00:00  DUNWOD  61760          20.85   
3  12/01/2016 00:00  GENESE  61753          16.16   
4  12/01/2016 00:00     H Q  61844          15.73   

   Marginal Cost Losses ($/MWHr)  Marginal Cost Congestion ($/MWHr)  
0                           1.21                              -4.45  
1                           0.11                              -0.45  
2                           1.58                              -2.99  
3                          -0.49                              -0.36  
4                          -0.55                               0.00
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. Could you point me towards some documentation or examples so I can understand a bit better what is going on in the custom file reader. I feel like it is better to understand this, rather than just copying it

Comment: Also my plan was to iterate over all entries in master_links list using a for loop, and then append them together. With the code as it stands you this only picks out '20161201damlbmp_zone.csv' when you define df

Comment: Why do you need the filename as the second entry in fetch_multi_csv_zip_from_url() ?

Comment: Except for pandas these are all standard Python.  I have added some links, and a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: I have been using this code very successfully up until now, with many different zips of csv files. However with a new file that I have tried to use I get this error;

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

I believe this is because the new file I am trying to run has a zip within a zip.

Comment: I imagine that you would have to change the line starting with 
    return {name: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name)

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic, I am so glad this code is proving useful.  I suggest if you would like additional help, that you post a new question. You can link from the new question to this question to help explain, but be sure to make the new question an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you like, you can put a comment here to alert me to the new question.

Comment: That is a good idea, I have posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991084/how-to-open-a-csv-in-a-zip-in-a-zip-with-python